# android - passing string builder value from 1 activity to another

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I want to pass string builder value from main menu reverse geocode method activity to send sms automatically activity

this is my code:
menu.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import mo.locationtracking.GPSTracker;
import mo.sms.IncomingSms;
import info.MonitoringObjek.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button bTambah;
    private Button bLihat;
    //private Button blokasi;
    GPSTracker gps;
    private TextView myAddress;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.menu);
          myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(info.MonitoringObjek.R.id.lokasisekarang);
        //  blokasi=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lokasi);
        //  blokasi.setOnClickListener(this);
          bTambah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tambah);
          bTambah.setOnClickListener(this);
          bLihat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_view);
          bLihat.setOnClickListener(this);
         // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(Menu.this);
         // check if GPS enabled        
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                getMyLocationAddress(latitude, longitude);
                gps.stopUsingGPS();
                // \n is for new line
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.button_tambah :
                Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateData.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.button_view :
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ViewData.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
        }
    }

public void getMyLocationAddress(double latitude,double longitude) {

        Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {

              //Place your latitude and longitude
              List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);

              if(addresses != null) {

                  Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                  StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();

                  for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                  }
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am at: "+strAddress.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  myAddress.setText("I am at: " +strAddress.toString());

                  Intent intentsms = new Intent (Menu.this,IncomingSms.class);
                  intentsms.putExtra("strAddress",strAddress.toString());
                  startActivity(intentsms);

              }

              else
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  //myAddress.setText("No location found..!");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not retrieve address please check your GPS and Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 gps.showSettingsAlert();
                 myAddress.setText("Could not Retrive Address!");
        }
    }
}
```

i want strAdress string builder value pass to this activity

IncomingSMS.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import mo.database.Menu;


public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    //final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    public final String WHEREAREYOU = "halo";



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Intent intentsms= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        final String strAddress = intentsms.getStringExtra("strAddress");
        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] tempsms = new SmsMessage[messages.length]; 
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                    tempsms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = tempsms[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = tempsms[i].getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                //  sms.sendTextMessage("+00000000", null,"message :"+ message, 
                            //null, null);


                } // end for loop
                for (SmsMessage msg : tempsms) {

                    //String phoneNumber = msgLocation.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    if (message.equals(WHEREAREYOU)){
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                     sms.sendTextMessage("+628563105567", null,"message :"+ strAddress, 
                                            null, null);}
                }
              } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }

}
```

but it return some error in incomingsms.java like this  The method getIntent() is undefined for the type

I don't know what's wrong

Comment: IncomingSms is a receiver not an activity. Use `sendBroadcast(intentsms);` instead of `startActivity(intentsms);`

Comment: i change intent menu.java like this 
Intent intent = new Intent (Menu.this,IncomingSms.class);
            intent.putExtra("strAddress",strAddress.toString());
            sendBroadcast(intent);
and 
incoming sms.java like this 
final String strAddress = intent.getStringExtra("strAddress");
but it returns null in strAddress and in sms i receive it returns message:null ??
i think that value not passed

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent();` is a method of `Activity` class and not of `BroadcastReceiver`.

If you want to use the `Intent` that you passed from the `Activity` you can use `intent` that you receive on `onReceive`.

So remove `Intent intentsms= getIntent();` and replace `intentsms` with `intent`

Comment: i change intent menu.java like this 
Intent intent = new Intent (Menu.this,IncomingSms.class);
            intent.putExtra("strAddress",strAddress.toString());
            sendBroadcast(intent);
and 
incoming sms.java like this 
final String strAddress = intent.getStringExtra("strAddress");
but it returns null in strAddress and in sms i receive it returns message:null ??
i think that value not passed

Comment: You can check if it is passed by using `intent.hasExtra("strAddress")`. If it is true then it is passed but it is passed null